# How to use "enum" with object Pooling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created an object pooling function, and when I call a Get() function in a player script, I don't want to pass it a number like `Get(0)`, but instead I want to call it like `Get((int)ObjPrefabs.PlayerBullet)`.

So I tried to use "enum", but I don't know how to assign the prefab object to enum.

```cs
public class ObjectManagerFirst : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;

    public enum ObjPrefabs {PlayerBullet};
    List<GameObject>[] pools;

    void Awake()
    {
        pools = new List<GameObject>[prefabs.Length];

        for (int index = 0; index < pools.Length; index++)
        {
            pools[index] = new List<GameObject>();
        }
    }

    public GameObject Get(int index)
    {
        GameObject select = null;
            
        foreach(GameObject item in pools[index])
        {

            if(!item.activeSelf)
            {       
                select = item;
                select.SetActive(true);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!select)
        {
            select = Instantiate(prefabs[index], transform);
            pools[index].Add(select);
        }

        return select;
    }
}
```

This is current way I call it in the Player Script:

`GameObject bullet = objectManager.Get(0);`

But I want:

`GameObject bullet = objectManager.Get((int)ObjPrefabs.PlayerBullet);`

I tried already tried the following, but it didn't work:

```cs
List<int> ObjList = new List<int>();
int value = ObjList[(int)ObjPrefabs.PlayerBullet]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign int values to enum and then pass it to function here is an example

```
enum ObjPrefabs
{
    PlayerBullet = 0,
    EnemyBullet = 1
}
```

and then call your Get function like this

```
GameObject bullet = objectManager.Get((int)ObjPrefabs.PlayerBullet);
```

and it'll work.

Comment: @Debug Don't forget that if someone successfully answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer. That tells everyone that your question has been solved, and it also awards some fun internet points.

Comment: `enum` by default already **has** `int` values .. and why not rather pass on the `enum` instead of casting to `int` ..?

Comment: Yes @derHugo you are right. But he want to call like this `GameObject bullet = objectManager.Get((int)ObjPrefabs.PlayerBullet);` so I provide this solution. enum has already int default values but in his case it is required to assign those values because Get function is depends on Index.

Comment: What you provide are the exact same default índices if using `enum ObjPrefabs { PlayerBullet, EnemyBullet }`

Comment: @derHugo Never mind. Do you want me to Delete my answer ?

Comment: I wouldn't say delete it .. I would rather point out "OP, what hinders you from just doing that since the enum by default should already just work as index" .. the issue here seems rather that OP wants a drop-down for the available prefabs I note now .. so none of our answers gives that so far I guess :'D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `int` for the index why not rather stick to the `enum` and use a

```
private Dictionary<ObjPrefabs, XXX> pools;
```

and rather use

```
public GameObject Get(ObjPrefabs type)
{
    if(!pools.TryGetValue(type, out var pool)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Pool for {type} has not been initialized!");
        return null;
    }

    // otherwise get object from "pool"
}
```

For the `XXX` see below

---

Now to the pool itself .. an array is fine but even better would be to e.g. simply use a `Queue`.

I would recommend a more complex but easier to handle pooling approach:

```
[Serializable]
public class Pool
{
    public class PoolObject : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Pool _pool;

        public void Initialize (Pool pool)
        {
            _pool = pool;
        }

        // Use this component and method to release instances instead of calling Destroy!
        public void Release()
        {
            _pool.Release(this);
        }

        private void OnDestroy ()
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Destroyed a pooled object! Rather use Release!", this);
            _pool.OnDestroyed(this);
        }
    }

    // In theory you could even get rid of this enum and use the prefab itself as key ;)
    [SerializeField] private ObjPrefab _type;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _prefab;

    [SerializeField] [Min(1)] private int _initialAmount;

    private readonly Queue<PoolObject> _availableInstances = new();
    private readonly List<PoolObject> _hotInstaces = new();

    public ObjPrefabs Type => _type;

    public void Initialize (Transform inactiveParent)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < _initialAmount; i++)
        {
            var instance = CreateInstance();
            instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            _availableInstances.Enqueue(instance);
        }
    }

    private PoolObject CreateInstance ()
    {
        var instance = Instantiate (_prefab, inactiveParent);
        if(! instance.TryGetComponent<PoolObject>(out var obj))
        {
            obj = instance.AddComponent<PoolObject>();
        }

        obj.Initialize(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroyed (PoolObject obj)
    {
        hotInstaces.Remove(obj);
    }

    public PoolObject GetInstance()
    {
        var instance = _avaialableInstances.Count != 0 ? _availableInstances.Dequeue() : CreateInstance();
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        hotInstances.Add(instance);
        return instance;
    }

    public void Release(PoolObject instance)
    {
        if(_hotInstances.Remove(instance))
        {
            instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            _availableInstances.Enqueue(instance);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"{instance} isn't an active object!");
        }
    }
}
```

And then finally you would use

```
[SerializeField] private Pool[] _pools;

private readonly Dictionary<ObjPrefabs, Pool> _activePools = new();

private void Awake ()
{
    foreach(var pool in _pools)
    {
        if(_activePools.ContainsKey(pool.Type))
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Duplicate pools for type {Type}!");
            continue;
        }

        pool.Initialize(transform);
        _activePools[pool.Type] = pool;
    }
}

public Pool.PoolObject Get(ObjPrefabs type)
{
    if(!pools.TryGetValue(type, out var pool)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Pool for {type} has not been initialized!");
        return null;
    }

    return pool.GetInstance();
}
```